# Find the uniformly most powerful test for this exponential distribution, and find the approximate value of c

Tags: likelihood, exponential-distribution, likelihood-ratio

So I am given that the distribution is exponential

$f(x|\lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x >  0$

I am also given that there is an independent sample size $n$, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$

I am given that the null hypothesis $H_0 : \lambda = 1$
and the alternative hypothesis $H_a : \lambda > 1$. So I noticed that this is a composite hypothesis so I have the use the uniformly most powerful test rather than Neymann Pearson.

I am asked to show that the uniformly most powerful test of $H_0$ is of the form “reject $H_0$ if $T < c$”, for some value c, where T is the sample total.

Then the next part says; suppose that $n = 100$, and the chosen significance level is $0.05$. Find, approximately, the value of c for this test

So to start this off I have done the likelihood ratio

$LR = \frac {l(\lambda_a)}{l(\lambda_0)}$

and I have found $l(\lambda_0) = e^{-\sum_{i=0}^n x_i} = e^{-n\bar x}$

I then find $l(\lambda_a) = \lambda_a^n e^{-\lambda_a\sum_{i=0}^n x_i}$

This gives me a likelihood ratio

$LR = \lambda_a^ne^{-(\lambda_a-1)n\bar x} = \lambda_a^ne^{-(\lambda_a-1)T}$

Where T is the sum total.

This satisfies the statement 'reject $H_0$ if $T < c$'

now onto the next part with $n = 100$ with significance level 0.05I don't really know what to do here so any hints would be extremely useful.

I guess that $\lambda_a^ne^{-(\lambda_a-1)n\bar x} = \lambda_a^ne^{-(\lambda_a-1)T} < K$ for some K

and that $T = 100\bar x$

ANy tips would be great. Thank you

Comment: The null is not composite, because it is the *single* state of nature described by $\lambda=1$.

Comment: @whuber It's a composite alternative hypothesis. The UMP test is used when testing a simple null hypothesis against a composite alternative hypothesis

Comment: So $LR(T)$ is a decreasing function of $T$, thus $LR(T) > c_1$ iff $T < c_2$ for some constant $c_1, c_2$. As to $T$, sum of exponential variables has a nice known distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad Yeah, that's the part I understand. But I don't know how to find the approximate value of c

Comment: Well, if you know the distirbution of $T$, then finding $c$ such that $P(T < c) = \alpha$ should not be a problem, just use appriopriate quantile.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad Is Erlang distribution the distribution of T? Because I've never seen that before. The distributions I do are like, exponential, uniform, gamma, normal etc But never seen this Erlang distribution

Comment: Its a special case of Gamma

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad Yeah it $Ga(1,\lambda)$ but I still don't know how to get T from that. I know expectation is $\frac {1}{\lambda}$ and variance is  $\frac {1}{\lambda^2}$

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad Is it because n is large I can approximate to be normal N(1,1)?

Comment: I don't get your problem, use as $c$ a quantile of $Gamma$, if you have to get an exact value look it up in a quantile table.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad I don't have gamma tables. Only T tables, Z tables and Chi squared tables. I really don't know how to go about getting T so any help would be great

Comment: The entire point to UMP tests is to deal with composite nulls. You don't need most of this machinery with a simple null: you only need the N-P lemma.  I am suggesting you are overcomplicating this problem. BTW, chi-squared distributions *are* Gamma distributions, so you do have Gamma tables.

Comment: @whuber Neymann Pearson only works for both the null and alternate hypothesis to be simple. In this case $H_0 : \lambda = 1$ is equivalent to  $H_0 : \lambda \le 1$

Comment: If you wish to view those two nulls as equivalent, then indeed you need to consider UMP tests.  But that's not what you have been asked to do.  As such, by making a simple null into a composite one, you have complicated the question and introduced extraneous considerations into its solutions.  Of course you will still get the same answer, but you're working far too hard to get it.

Comment: @whuber http://puu.sh/w3C9g/0fc570afd4.png There's the question, so let me know how you'd go about doing it. I still don't know how to do part c, so any help with that would be nice

Comment: I would start at the step you skipped in the problem statement: having found the *form* of the test, you need to compute the threshold $c$. It is determined by the need to make the false positive rate equal to $\alpha$ under the null. Writing down that rate in terms of $c, n,$ and $\alpha$ enables you to find $c$ in terms of $n$ and $\alpha$. Then you can just plug in $n=100$ and $\alpha=0.05$ to answer the question. (Please notice that your ability to compute this rate relies on the fact that $H_0$ is *simple* and not composite!)

Comment: @whuber I never said H_0 is composite though. Could you please show me what to do as I am clueless and am now stressing out

Comment: It's a straightforward calculation, nothing more, because (a) $H_0$ tells you the distribution of $T$ and (b) the test is expressed solely in terms of $T$ and $c$.  Sit back for a few minutes, take a break, when you come back, approach this as a simple problem.  If you know that the sum of iid exponential variates has a Gamma distribution, you'll likely get it right away.  Otherwise you should begin by looking up or working out that fact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59458/discussion-between-user162934-and-whuber).